# Infinite series involving Lambert W function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Suppose we have a sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $-e^{-1} \leq x_k \leq 0 \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. Is the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} W_0 (x_k)
$$
necessarily finite? If not, what conditions would we need on $x_k$?

Comment: (Not the DV). Participants at Mathematics Stackexchange look unfavorably upon pure problem statements. Please provide some context to the question. Where did this come up, what are you ultimately trying to accomplish? Please point out what you have tried so far to solve this on your own and why this did not work out.